# Combine multiple different images from a directory into a canvas sized 3x6

Tags: python, canvas, python-imaging-library

I itirate to images of a directory. I want from those images to create a 3x6 canvas, a new image that will display the images of that directory side by side into a single image / canvas. Each image must be a different image. Side by side. –

I have the following code. It tries to read the image filenames from a directory that are stored into a list. Then it tries to copy / combine each image into a 3x6 canvas. However, the result that i want happens not.
What i am doing wrong?

```
import Image
import os
import PIL
import glob
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# path
path = "/media/"
listing = os.listdir(path)

# getting all path+filename in a list
npath=[]
im=[]
for infile in listing:
  im.append(infile)
  npath.append(os.path.join(path, infile))

#creates a new empty image, RGB mode, and size 400 by 400.
new_im = Image.new('RGB', (2100,2400))


#Here I resize my opened image, so it is no bigger than ****
#Iterate through a grid with some spacing, to place my image
for i in xrange(0,2100,700):
    for j in xrange(0,2400, 400):
        for imagefile in npath:
            im=Image.open(imagefile)
            im.thumbnail((1000,1000))
            #paste the image at location i,j:
            new_im.paste(im, (i,j))
            new_im.show()
#saving
new_im.save('/media/test.png')
```

The solution

```
import Image
import os
import PIL
import glob
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# path
path = "/media/"
listing = os.listdir(path)


# getting all path+filename in a list
npath=[]
im=[]

for infile in listing:
  im.append(infile)
  npath.append(os.path.join(path, infile))

#creates a new empty image, RGB mode, and size 400 by 400.
new_im = Image.new('RGB', (2500,3000))

for i in xrange(0,2500,800):
    for j in xrange(0,3000, 500):
        im=Image.open(npath.pop(0))
        im.thumbnail((1000,1000))
        #paste the image at location i,j:
        new_im.paste(im, (i,j))
    new_im.save('/media/test.png')
```

Comment: It's not clear what you're expecting. What is going wrong? And how do you expect it.

Comment: I itirate to images of a directory. I want from those images to create a 3x6 canvas. Each image must be a different image. Side by side. @rfkortekaas

Comment: But what is the problem that you have? Are the images in the wrong place, is there an error?

Comment: Yes. Not a single canvas with 3x6=18 unique images is created. Instead, it is created a canvas that contain 17 same images + the last that was itirated. The loop is wrong. I dont know how to fix it, in order all 18 images to appear on the canvas side by side using pil image library. @rfkortekaas

Comment: For each position you are iterating over all the images so they are placed over each other. Remove the for loop and take the first image from the list and delete it from the list.

Comment: can you provide a sample code showing me what you mean? Which for loop to remove? Why to delete the first image? How this can be done?

Comment: Think about what your code is doing. It pastes _all the files_ in `npath` at _every_ `(i, j)` position calculated, so you'll end up only seeing the last one at each position.

Comment: The hardcoded numbers shown in both your question (and the "solution" you added to it) don't add up. If each thumbnail is 1000x1000, then for a 3x6 grid of them, I would expect the canvas of the resulting image size to be 3000x6000. This surprises me since you say you're a statistician. Likewise, it seems like the code would need modification to deal gracefully with cases where there were more or less than exactly 18 (3x6) image files in the directory.

Comment: You can see the picture here https://postimg.org/image/n1fbepnpt/                      @martineau Note that the dimensions in image thumbnail are wrong. You have some right there. Because my image is not square (1000x1000). I found the code elsewhere and i didnt change these numbers to represent mines (they were 100x100). Therefore, i must changed one of them at least in order to represent the 2500 dimension in a right fashion 1000x516. Therefore, it will become about 3000X3096. So, yes, i didnt look at these numbers. Code had all my priorities :P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do not iterate over the image list for every position, consume the list instead:

```
for i in xrange(0, 2100, 700):
    for j in xrange(0, 2400, 400):
        try:
            filepath = npath.pop(0)
        except IndexError:
            break
        im = Image.open(filepath)
        im.thumbnail((1000,1000))
        # paste the image at location i,j
        new_im.paste(im, (i,j))
    else:
        continue  # executed if inner loop ended normally (no break)
    break  # executed if 'continue' was skipped (break occurred)
```

Comment: It produces the following error while npath previously is full of data. However, after the loop is empty. `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 2820, in run_code
    exec code_obj in self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns
  File "<ipython-input-41-9ce5c17ed34d>", line 25, in <module>
    im=Image.open(npath.pop(0))
IndexError: pop from empty list`

Comment: Yes, pop is consuming the list. So appearantly there are nother enough images in the list. Add a try catch to check for an empty list

Comment: i put 18 images on path variables. Again the same error i take.

Comment: The result is the following image. `http://pictub.club/image/V3CLF` as you can see it does not contain unique images.

Comment: problem solved. Thanks! It works like charm. I will upload the code

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're trying to do could be solved in a very general way by using  coroutines as described in [PEP 342 — Coroutines via Enhanced Generators](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0342/). Below is code to handle creating and laying-out thumbnail images onto a grid of any size. It will potentially generate multiple thumbnail pages, depending on how many images there are and how many will fit on the grid until it is full.

I tried to avoid using hardcoded numbers to increase its flexibility. Both the thumbnail size and grid layout are now variables.

**Note**: All the calls that would actually create and save the thumbnail output images has been commented-out, so to make it easy and fast run in test mode. You'll need to uncomment them to actually get it to do produce any output images.

```
from glob import iglob
from PIL import Image
import os

def thumbnailer(thumbpath, grid, thumb_size, background_color):
    """ Coroutine to receive image file names and produce thumbnail pages of
        them laid-out in a grid.
    """
    page_num = 0
    page_extent = grid[0]*thumb_size[0], grid[1]*thumb_size[1]

    try:
        while True:
            paste_cnt = 0
            #new_img = Image.new('RGB', page_extent, background_color)
            for x in xrange(0, page_extent[0], thumb_size[0]):
                for y in xrange(0, page_extent[1], thumb_size[1]):
                    try:
                        filepath = (yield)
                    except GeneratorExit:
                        print('GeneratorExit received')
                        return

                    filename = os.path.basename(filepath)
                    print('{} thumbnail -> ({}, {})'.format(filename, x, y))
                    #thumbnail_img = Image.open(filepath)
                    #thumbnail_img.thumbnail(thumb_size)
                    #new_img.paste(thumbnail_img, (x,y))
                    paste_cnt += 1
                else:
                    continue  # no break, continue outer loop
                break  # break occurred, terminate outer loop

            print('====> thumbnail page completed')
            if paste_cnt:
                page_num += 1
                print('Saving thumbpage{}.png'.format(page_num))
                #img.save(
                #    os.path.join(thumbpath, 'thumbpage{}.png'.format(page_num)))
    finally:
        print('====> finally')
        if paste_cnt:
            page_num += 1
            print('Saving thumbpage{}.png'.format(page_num))
            #img.save(
            #    os.path.join(thumbpath, 'thumbpage{}.png'.format(page_num)))

path = '/media'
#npath = [infile for infile in iglob(os.path.join(path, '*.png'))]
npath = ['image{}.png'.format(i) for i in xrange(1, 37+1)]  # test names

coroutine = thumbnailer(path, (3,6), (1000,1000), 'white')
coroutine.next()  # start it

for filepath in npath:
    coroutine.send(filepath)

print('====> closing coroutine')
coroutine.close()
```

Here's the output from the above which produces 3 thumbnail pages from the 37 dummy image files laid-out upon a 3x6 grid:

```
image1.png thumbnail -> (0, 0)
image2.png thumbnail -> (0, 1000)
image3.png thumbnail -> (0, 2000)
image4.png thumbnail -> (0, 3000)
image5.png thumbnail -> (0, 4000)
image6.png thumbnail -> (0, 5000)
image7.png thumbnail -> (1000, 0)
image8.png thumbnail -> (1000, 1000)
image9.png thumbnail -> (1000, 2000)
image10.png thumbnail -> (1000, 3000)
image11.png thumbnail -> (1000, 4000)
image12.png thumbnail -> (1000, 5000)
image13.png thumbnail -> (2000, 0)
image14.png thumbnail -> (2000, 1000)
image15.png thumbnail -> (2000, 2000)
image16.png thumbnail -> (2000, 3000)
image17.png thumbnail -> (2000, 4000)
image18.png thumbnail -> (2000, 5000)
====> thumbnail page completed
Saving thumbpage1.png
image19.png thumbnail -> (0, 0)
image20.png thumbnail -> (0, 1000)
image21.png thumbnail -> (0, 2000)
image22.png thumbnail -> (0, 3000)
image23.png thumbnail -> (0, 4000)
image24.png thumbnail -> (0, 5000)
image25.png thumbnail -> (1000, 0)
image26.png thumbnail -> (1000, 1000)
image27.png thumbnail -> (1000, 2000)
image28.png thumbnail -> (1000, 3000)
image29.png thumbnail -> (1000, 4000)
image30.png thumbnail -> (1000, 5000)
image31.png thumbnail -> (2000, 0)
image32.png thumbnail -> (2000, 1000)
image33.png thumbnail -> (2000, 2000)
image34.png thumbnail -> (2000, 3000)
image35.png thumbnail -> (2000, 4000)
image36.png thumbnail -> (2000, 5000)
====> thumbnail page completed
Saving thumbpage2.png
image37.png thumbnail -> (0, 0)
====> closing coroutine
GeneratorExit received
====> finally
Saving thumbpage3.png
```